# ERROR "Connection.close() has already been called. Invalid operation in this state." when using hadoop to export data to mysql

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote a MapReduce program to export data to MySQL.I used the DBOutputFormat class and jdbc for MySQL.When the data is small(e.g.2M),everthing was OK.But when my data was larger (e.g.**5Mbytes**), it errored with the exception **"Connection.close() has already been called. Invalid operation in this state."**
The **"wait_timeout"** value in my.cnf is **28800**,it is enough.But the same problem I searched in Google was all about the **"wait_timeout"** in my.cnf.I am fresher to jdbc.I don't konw if the jdbc or hadoop should be configured and how.Or can I reconnect the mysql connection if closed and how.Please give me some code.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.